# jsTree v.3 lazy loading with ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jstree

I've been making a jstree lazy loading with ajax call, but i met a problem.

my code brings json data with 1 depth successfully.
however when I click or select node, it doesn't bring its child.
I dont know what my problem is.

this is my javascript code

```js
$("#tree").jstree({
       'core' : {
        'data' : {
            'url' : function(node) {
                return'/url/getTree';
               },
            'type' : 'GET',
            'data' : function(node) {
                return {
                   parentId : node.id ==="#" ? 0 : node.id,
                   searchdepth : 1
                    }
                },
            'success' : function(data) {
               return data.list
              }
          },
         'check_callback':true,
          }, 
      "plugins" : ["json_data"]
         });
```

and my result data is like this

```html
[{"id":"1","text":"node_1","data":{"selected":"N"},"children":[{"id":"3","text":"node_3","data":{"selected":"N"}},{"id":"2","text":"node_2","data":{"selected":"N"}}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON document does not seem to be correct. The document needs to contain **exactly** one array which contains **only** the children of the node you requested information for.

So using your example, when you request information for node with id 1 your json needs to look like this:

```
[
   {"id":"3","text":"node_3","data":{"selected":"N"}, "children":true/false},
   {"id":"2","text":"node_2","data":{"selected":"N"}, "children":true/false}
]
```